# How to get users in role specified in channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using `discord.py` 2.1.0, and I want to get users with role id specified in text channel.

I am trying this approach, but it does not work:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(channel.guild.roles, id=1060070158267326565)
users = role.members
print(users)
```

output :

```
[]
```

Comment: Do you have the `members` intent, both in code & on the developer dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems in your code.

Try to give the bot that role and see, if it returns your bot then:

- Make sure that `guild_members` intent is enabled in the dashboard.

[image]

Also your code should contain:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True


client = commands.Bot(intents=intents)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you either did not enable the required intent, or there is actually no members with this role.

For intents, check the discord developers portal and enable them. Don't forget to do it in your code too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).